# Xcode can't update to version 6.2

Tags: xcode, xcode6

Yesterday I updated Xcode 6.1.1 to Xcode 6.2 but after update when I see about Xcode it's still showing Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a).
Any idea why?

**Note:** I already go to the App store and check it, but there is showing that it's updated and I can only open it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download full 2.6 GB xcode completly and remove old one and try it . will fix your problm.Also check for OS compatibility.

Comment: I hit the "Update" button on the App store for Xcode 6.2 this morning. After 2 hours, I restarted and, as above, find that my Xcode version is 6.1.1. I'd like to follow your advice, but this sounds like I have to dl the entire thing again. Or is this morning's download stored somewhere on my drive? I've searched with Xcode as a keyword, but only turned up the existing version 6.1.1. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by reinstalling it.

i think the issue was i updated X-code first and then update Mac OS X.

so i remove X-code from mac and then reinstall it .

Answer (score 0):

It says on `compatibility: OS X 10.9.4 or later`, I currently run `10.10.2 beta` and prepare to upgrade to `10.10.3 beta`. It said first after download that I did not have sufficient disc space, so I stopped a few processes and compacted some temporary folders, to get 10G available. From the update tab in the `App Store`, now the "update" button goes grey when pushing it (no messages), and nothing happens.

I even have renamed my old Xcode (`6.1.1`) to Xcode_old.app, but doesn't seem to help. Do I really need to download it from the developer centre again?

(I know `App Store` stores updates and partly downloaded files under hashed filenames somewhere in `/Library`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required OS.  For example, xcode 6.3.2 requires Yosemite (v10.10):
[image]

You can view this info at https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/