# Xcode version update

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently use xcode version 8.2.1. I would like to update it to the latest version or at least to a version that is supported by iOS 10.3.2.

The app store doesn't show any available update for my xode and when I try to update it on the terminal, I get a message saying that I am at the latest version. I'm guessing this is because I am using the latest version of xcode8.2 or something?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978883/xcode-cant-update-to-version-6-2) and it says I need to reinstall my xcode. So, could I update my existing xcode without having to install another version?

Comment: Sometime we don't see the Xcode update in Updates tab in AppStore.
So search Xcode in AppStore.

Comment: You can check this link and download latest version for Xcode  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file

Comment: The output is: "Xcode.app version (11.0) and Xcode Command Line Tools version (10.3)
may not be compatible."

Answer (score 2):

> App store is the only source to updating (through Commandline or
>   directly) Xcode or others apps.If store itself no updation of app.Then
>   probably have to wait for it instead of installing another version
>   from Apple download section.

Yes.Sometimes it happens to me.App store not showing new version of Xcode in Updates Tab.So i m going directly to search Xcode.

My current Xcode version is **Xcode 8.3.3**
But App store shows only stable version as latest version (currently
Xcode 8.3.3)
If you wanna more **latest beta version** product You can get from below
[From Apple Downloads section](https://developer.apple.com/download/)

[image]

i checked via command line also using below command But the result is same.
`softwareupdate --list` to see what's available.

Result :

```
Apples-Mac-mini:~ apple$ softwareupdate --list
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Software Update found the following new or updated software:
   * macOS Sierra Update-10.12.5
    macOS Sierra Update (10.12.5), 873261K [recommended] [restart]
   * RemoteDesktopClient-3.9.3
    Remote Desktop Client Update (3.9.3), 8587K [recommended]
   * iTunesXPatch-12.6.1
    iTunes (12.6.1), 179760K [recommended]
Apples-Mac-mini:~ apple$
```

You can updated Xcode or other software if it's available using below command

```
softwareupdate --install <product name>
```

You can get more comments from here [Software update tool](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but command line doesn't show an available update for xcode. I do have a macOS update available, but I am on 10.12, which does support a higher version of xcode. I am happy to work with a stable release and am not exactly looking for a beta release as such. I'm just looking for a way to update it, instead of installing another version.

Comment: Yes i understood your point.. the way to update Xcode is only source from App store (either you installing from app store directly or commandline).If app store itself no updation then have to wait for it.

Comment: Oh, Okay... Thanks!

Comment: of course you aware of that even you try to install beta or updating version from Apple Downloads section.It will install separately it wont override existing version.So what i'm thinking app store itself before installing new one it could delete previous one.

Answer (score 2):

App-store is the only way to update the Xcode to the latest one.

First, make sure that you are running on the required version of OSX (macOS 10.12 or later) to support the version of Xcode 8.3.3.

If you are on the required version of OSX and the App-store not showing any updates, that should be a bug with the App-store app. Reinstall is the only option in this case.

**Note:**

The Xcode update (to 8.3.3) will take almost 4.5 GB of data

Direct Xcode 8.3.3 download will take exact 4.54 GB of data

So, I really not seeing any differences in both except the way of downloading.

Comment: Thanks @Shamsudheen. I was of the opinion that the xcode update wouldn't be that bulky since it would be an update and not a fresh install. Are you sure the update from 8.2.1 to 8.3.3 would be 4.5 Gigs?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same earlier days. I updated OSX and Xcode just before two days and the Xcode update was more than 4.5 GB. Then, I read about the Appstore update process and understood that, almost all apps downloaded from the Apps Store are full (self-containing) updates or upgrades. They completely replace the updated app. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213291/why-are-updates-so-extremely-large

Answer (score 1):

Just login to your Apple developer account and in [download](https://developer.apple.com/download/) section download the latest Xcode and install it. Then from now whenever the new Xcode will available you'll get notify for an update.

OR
[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Comment: he asking ..could I update my existing xcode without having to install another version?

Comment: ok, I got it. But he need to work on 10.3.2 
So, either update the Xcode or install the latest version, it should work as I think.